# Minimum size of cut-vertex set

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a bipartite graph $G$ with bipartition $(X,Y)$. A new graph $G^{'}$ is created by adding two vertices $s$ and $t$ such that $s$ is connected to all vertices in $X$ and $t$ is connected to all vertices in $Y$. What is the minimum size of a vertex set that disconnects $s$ and $t$?

Is it the minimum size of vertex cover of $G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum size of a vertex set that disconnects *s* and *t* in $G'$ is $\nu(G)$, the size of a maximum matching in $G$. Divide the vertices of $X$ and $Y$ into two parts each, those vertices that are in the matching ($X_0$ and $Y_0$) and those that are not ($X_1$ and $Y_1$):

```
         s
    /---------\
X_0 ooo...ooo o X_1
    |||.M.|||×
Y_0 ooo...ooo ooo Y_1
    \-----------/
          t
```

Because the matching $M$ is maximal, there cannot be any edges between $X_1$ and $Y_1$, though there may be edges between $X_0$ and $Y_1$ or between $Y_0$ and $X_1$. Deleting $X_0$ disconnects *s* and *t*, because that leaves no edges connecting $X$ and $Y$; similarly, deleting $Y_0$ disconnects *s* and *t*, and $\nu(G)$ is an upper bound on the order of the desired minimal cut-vertex set. $\nu(G)$ is also a lower bound, because cutting less than that number of vertices must preserve at least one edge in $M$ and hence a path from *s* to *t*.

We have thus proved rigorously that the answer to the question is $\nu(G)$. Since $G$ is bipartite, by Kőnig's theorem $\nu(G)$ is also the size of the minimum vertex cover of $G$.

Comment: If $\nu(G)$ has to be same as the size of the minimum vertex cover of $G$?

Comment: Those two values are indeed equivalent for bipartite graphs. I have edited the answer to include this.

Comment: According to Konig's theorem, vertex cover of $G$ is the maximal match but why it has to be same as cut-vertex set $\nu(G)$?

Comment: While Kőnig's theorem only states an equivalence between the sizes of minimal vertex cover and maximal matching, it is trivial to construct an explicit relation between them: take a maximal matching, then a minimal vertex cover is obtained by choosing from each edge in the matching one of the two vertices it connects.